# Handle back button with useHistory in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

If a user navigates to `www.example.com/one` inside of this there is one more `www.example.com/two`

if the user clicks back button in a page `www.example.com/two`  it should back to the `www.example.com/one`. if the user clicks back button in a page `www.example.com/one` it should back to the home page `www.example.com`

Comment: functional components or class components ?

Comment: functional components

Answer (score 0):

use `onClick={() => props.history.goBack()}` inside your button
like

```
  <button type="button" onClick={() => props.history.goBack()}>Go Back</button>
```